# Alarm Clock application source code

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-2.3-gingerbread

Is there a way to get the `Alarm Application` source code for customizing the existing default source code availble in `Android 2.3`.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523350/android-alarm-clock-ui

Answer (score 32):

You can download the app from the Android github mirror.

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock

Or on the cyanogen mirror

https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_DeskClock

And because, you are a nice guy, you are wondering: *What is the license of that code?*

Glad you asked, because [according to the Android documentation](http://source.android.com/source/licenses.html) and [cyanogen's wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CyanogenMod), it's the **[Apache Software License 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)**

And as we all know, the Apache license 2.0 is **a nice license** for the all hackers. Even those who intend to make a buck or two. (you little capitalist scoundrels)

[image: License comparison]

Please note that, I didn't come up with that nice cheat sheet. [Someone else did.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/162136)

Comment: @carl: thanks. it was informative. I cloned the source as it is @ https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/AlarmClock.git
But I couldn't run the app in AndroidStudio. Am I doing something completely wrong?

Answer (score 9):

This is the version that's made and maintained by Google now in a move to keep the apps unbundled from the system so as to provide the apps and updates to everyone even if the OEMs don't provide system update.

Hence It's the one that's available from the Play store to download too. The one that's shared previously is the stock App which is quite old.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/

As the site of the source *may* keep changing, best way for you to figure it out is by visiting Android Open Source Project (AOSP) page and searching for the URL of the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can download whole android source tree including alarm app from here:

http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Comment: Hey @Caner, I have downloaded the source. I was wondering if you could point out where the alarm app's Classes and layouts are located.

Comment: I believe it is located inside "com.android.deskclock". Have a look from here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/deskclock/AlarmClock.java?av=f

Comment: @Caner: do I need to do everything mentioned @ https://source.android.com/source/requirements.html , in order to only play with Alarm app. I have windows machine with 8GB ram  so that Im not sure I have met the requirments they say.Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Cyanogenmod is dead. So, here's the latest Lineage DeskClock (Apache License 2.0) repository:

https://github.com/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_DeskClock