# Latest Android Alarm Clock Build

Tags: android, android-alarms

I have downloaded the default Android Alarm Clock App from the following URL:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/AlarmClock/
I have used the "master" link (then tree => tgz Package) found under the "Branches" header in order to download the Package. Meanwhile, upon importing the Package into Android Studio, I am prompted to convert the Package to Gradle. After performing this conversion, I am obtaining some errors during the Build process. Shouldn't there be an existing Package already built for Gradle?

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't there be an existing Package already built for Gradle?

No. The apps that are part of AOSP are designed to be built as part of a full build of the entire Android OS. They are not designed to be built as standalone apps using just the Android SDK, using Gradle or anything else.

Comment: According to padfoot's answer found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594637/alarm-clock-application-source-code, "This is the version that's made and maintained by Google now in a move to keep the apps unbundled from the system so as to provide the apps and updates to everyone". Doesn't this imply that the apps should now be independent from the OS?Thank you again.

Comment: @JF0001: I would assume that padfoot is referring to [this app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/) (linked to in the answer), which is not the app you are interested in. Moreover, if you look at the version history of the app from your question, it has not been updated in 7 years.

Comment: Thank you again CommonsWare. Yes, you are correct, I have included the wrong link in my initial post, and my apologies. Meanwhile, the package referenced in padfoot's post is the one I have actually downloaded and built, but for which I am obtaining errors.

Comment: @JF0001: Again, there is no requirement for any project in the AOSP to be able to be built as a standalone app using just the Android SDK.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Joseph